# call another controller method from an action method in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, controller

I am trying to call a second controller method from an action method.
I am able to call second controller method using

```
this.controller.get('controllers.secondController').method();
```

How can i call method of another controller from action method?
There is work around i know of like call the controller of the current action method which in turn calls the second controller method.

```
this.callFirstControllerMethod();
```

and then use

```
this.controller.get('controllers.secondController').method();
```

But is there a way to call the second controller method directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this kind of logic should not be on the controller, a controller should really only have actions that relate to the UI or the display of your model.

I would suggest to add an action in the route, that can access the controllers and invoke any methods you need.

```
// route.js
actions: {
  doSomething: function() {
    var controllerA = this.controllerFor('firstController');
    var controllerB = this.controllerFor('secondController');

    controllerA.doSomething();
    controllerB.doSomethingElse();
  }
}
```

Comment: the second controller I am calling is fetching some data that is not specific to the current page like that needs to used in may other pages. So I am fetching those data in the second controller and on a action on my first page i am invoking the second controller method to fetch the data. Is that the right approach from design perspective?